# SQL: Add a SUM(ColumnA) AS ColumnB to a query returning ColumnA

Tags: sql

I have a query that returns a number of columns, including ColumnA (which is numerical).
I want to add an additional column to the end of the query that returns the sum of ColumnA

| ColumnA | ColumnB |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 37 |
| 20 | 37 |
| 5 | 37 |
| 2 | 37 |

```
SELECT
    ColumnA,
    SUM(ColumnA) AS ColumnB
  FROM 
    Table
```

The code above doesn't work, but I'm not sure how to create something that will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this query:

```
SELECT ColumnA, (SELECT SUM(ColumnA) FROM table) as ColumnB
FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
SELECT
  ColumnA,
  ColumnASum
  FROM Table
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(columnA) ColumnASum FROM Table)
  ON TRUE;
```

Should work

Answer (score 0):

You could create a variable of the SUM() first.

```
DECLARE @ColumnB int
SET @ColumnB = (SELECT SUM(ColumnA) FROM Table)

SELECT ColumnA, @ColumnB
FROM Table
```

This should give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I would use CROSS APPLY.

```
SELECT Table.ColumnA
     ,CA.ColumnB
FROM Table
CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM(ColumnA) ColumnB FROM Table) CA
```

You basically define a subquery that outputs an aggregate value that you can have as another column.